# Conditional right click items in macos - finder

Tags: xcode, macos, finder

I'm trying to add right click items with NSMenuItem tools with Finder Inject. I need to change the items according to the path of the clicked file/folder. But it seems that, with finder inject, the menu items are generated before right-click.

In other words, I can't edit the MenuItems regarding on a condition that checks the path of the right-clicked file. Any ideas?

I've tried

```
-(NSMenuItem *)createMenuItem {     
    // I need to catch the path of the clicked item here.    
    NSMenuItem *menuItem = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"ITEM TITLE" action:@selector(myMethodClicked:) keyEquivalent:@""];
    [menuItem setTarget:self];     
    return menuItem;
}
```

I can get path of the clicked file with the method below, see the line:

```
NSArray *selectedFiles = [[ILFinderMenu sharedInstance] selectedItems];
```

But I need it before the menuItems are added. Whole function is also added below.

```
- (void)myMethodClicked:(id)sender {
    NSMenuItem *item = (NSMenuItem *)sender;
    NSMenu *submenu = [item submenu];
    
    NSArray *selectedFiles = [[ILFinderMenu sharedInstance] selectedItems];
    NSString *selectedFilePath = [selectedFiles objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *appPath = @"/eclipse/";
            
    if ([selectedFilePath rangeOfString:appPath].location != NSNotFound) {
        // disable backup
        NSMenuItem *backupMenuItem = [submenu itemAtIndex:1];
        [backupMenuItem setEnabled:NO];
        
        // enable share
        NSMenuItem *shareItem = [submenu itemAtIndex:0];
        [shareItem setEnabled:YES];
    } else {            
        // disable share
        NSMenuItem *backupMenuItem = [submenu itemAtIndex:0];
        [backupMenuItem setEnabled:NO];
        
        // enable backup
        NSMenuItem *shareItem = [submenu itemAtIndex:1];
        [shareItem setEnabled:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Better method to do this is to use [finder extensions](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/extensions/finder-sync-extensions/). If you need more flexibility, you can use notifications to communicate with the main app and change right click menu items dynamically. The official documentation has examples that can help. [Here](https://samiyuru.com/project/macOS-finder-right-click-menu) is an app that uses the approach to add custom right click menu items. The page has a link to the source.

Answer (score 0):

You should find another method for `MethodSwizzling`. Find method that will get called before menu are generated.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: No one will give you method name for MethodSwizzling. OP is overriding wrong method in finder plugin.